# httpd trying to access root-owned session files

Tags: httpd, selinux, server-crashes, session

While looking into what's been causing a server to lock up/crash, I found many selinux messages in /var/log/messages. For example:

`setroubleshoot: SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/httpd from getattr access on the file /tmp/sess_s5etafvc5ito5qi9icvpc17vi5. For complete SELinux messages. run sealert -l 9d054e4e-fc34-41a3-8fc5-4015026d2c6c`

Not sure if it is relevant, but group of these are preceded or followed by many lines of

`audispd: queue is full - dropping event`

Anyway, running the suggested sealert command gives

```
SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/httpd from getattr access on the file /tmp/sess_aa0iif62mu7nd4a4hb4g72slv3.

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests  ***************************

If you believe that httpd should be allowed getattr access on the sess_aa0iif62mu7nd4a4hb4g72slv3 file by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# grep httpd /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M mypol
# semodule -i mypol.pp
```

ls -l shows that it is owned by root

`-rw-------.  1 root   root      0 Dec  2 05:03 sess_aa0iif62mu7nd4a4hb4g72slv3`

I don't have a good understanding of the /tmp directory or sessions. There are session files owned by httpd, so why would httpd be trying to access root-owned session files? Why are there root-owned session files in the first place? Is this something to be concerned about, or fixed? Would hundreds or thousands of these result in the server locking up/kernel panic?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have an application engine, such as PHP, running as root. Verify the user owning the process for each of your server daemons through ps or top.

Comment: PHP, yes. I see several httpd processes owned by apache, and 2 owned by root (one with pid=1599 and ppid=1, the other with ppid=1599). All the other httpd processes have ppid=1599. From what I've read, the main server should run as `root`, and child processes run as `apache`.
Still not sure if anything is out of the ordinary